# A way to warp an image based on a map

Tags: python, image-processing, graphics, 3d, textures

I'm looking for a method where, given an two images (A and B, with A being an RGB image and B being a greyscale image storing the warping information) I can warp A relative to B.
To give you some context, this is pretty much the same technique used to artificially create a stereo image from a single image given depth information. In this case A would be the source image and B would be the depth map.

I was able to achieve something similar using this code

```
def map_pixels(input_image, input_map, N):
    """
    Shifts pixels of the input_image to the right based on the map information and a shift factor N.

    :param input_image: A (3, h, w) numpy array representing the RGB image.
    :param input_map: A (h, w) numpy array representing mapping information, values from 0 (far) to 1 (near).
    :param N: An integer representing the base number of pixels for the shift.
    :return: A (3, h, w) numpy array representing the shifted RGB image.
    """
    
    input_image = np.transpose(input_image, (2, 0, 1))
    input_map = input_map.astype(np.float32) / 255.0
    map_shifts = np.round(N * input_map).astype(int)  # Calculate the shift amount for each pixel

    
    
    # Initialize an array to hold the shifted image
    shifted_image = np.zeros_like(input_image)
    # Iterate through each channel of the image
    for c in range(input_image.shape[0]):  # For each color channel
        channel = input_image[c, :, :]  # Extract the current color channel

        print('CHANNEL SHAPE ' + str(channel.shape))
        # Iterate through each pixel in the channel
        for y in range(channel.shape[0]):  # For each row
            for x in range(channel.shape[1]):  # For each column
                shift = map_shifts[y, x]  # Determine how many pixels to shift
                if x + shift[1] < channel.shape[1]:  # Check if the shifted position is within bounds
                    shifted_image[c, y, x + shift] = channel[y, x]  # Shift the pixel

    shifted_image = np.transpose(shifted_image, (1, 2, 0))
    return shifted_image
```

The problem I'm facing here is that there is no filtering whatsoever, the pixels just get moved to their new location leaving some broken areas of black pixels and I would like to be able to add some smoothness to the shift.

I was wondering if anyone has any insight in this that they could share.

Note: This is only the function to shift the pixels to the right, I have 3 more functions for left, up and down that I want to be able to call separately.

Also I'm not invested in strictly using Numpy or ImageIO, any solution involving other systems like OpenCV is more than welcome

Thank you

Comment: Post your two images. You should use an inverse warp to avoid the gaps.  Let's say this is for moving in the X direction (horizontal). For each pixel in the two images, get the grayscale value relative to mid-gray. If positive, go to the left some scaled amount, get the color value at that location and put it at the original location.  Similarly if the the grayscale value relative to mid gray is negative, go to the right, get the color value at that location and put it in the original color value. I believe you can do that in Imagemagick or Python Wand, which uses Imagemagick.

Comment: either *pull* the pixels, which is easy because it's just a lookup, or get a textured triangle mesh and warp it, then draw it. this is graphics, not vision.